# Puppet defined resources and hiera json

Tags: puppet, hiera

Trying to use hiera with puppet. And i'm wondering how could i move something like this to hiera:

Definition:

```
define apache::namevirtualhost {
  $addr_port = $name

  # Template uses: $addr_port
  concat::fragment { "NameVirtualHost ${addr_port}":
    target  => $apache::ports_file,
    content => template('apache/namevirtualhost.erb'),
  }
}
```

Then in my super_node.pp:

```
apache::namevirtualhost { '*:80': }
```

How could i move '*:80' to hiera json file? Something like this (does not seem to work):

```
{
    "apache::namevirtualhost" : "*:80"
}
```

Same question if i include definitions multiple times, how could i move configuration to hiera:

```
  vagrant::box { 'dev.local':
    sshport       => '2223',
    ip            => '10.69.69.101'
  } 

  vagrant::box { 'it.local':
    sshport       => '2224',
    ip            => '10.69.69.102'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the hiera function in your manifests, so in your super_node.pp:

```
$namevirtualhost = hiera("apache::namevirtualhost")
apache::namevirtualhost { $namevirtualhost : }
```

Same for your boxes:

```
  vagrant::box { 'dev.local':
    sshport       => hiera("dev_local_sshport"),
    ip            => hiera("dev_local_ip"),
  }
```

First you should ensure that hiera database is properly configured by typing

```
hiera "apache::namevirtualhost"
```

From command_line

Comment: Have you tested your answer?: Your suggested 'apache::namevirtualhost { hiera("apache::namevirtualhost"): }' gives me "Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at ':'; expected '}'"

Comment: I'm sorry, but actually I can't check syntax and maybe puppet doesn't like `resource{ foo(): }` syntax. But hiera calls are as printed, and will work as far as command-line `hiera variablename` does.